# Restrict table view unless select all cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a table view in which i'm populating data getting from my service. the data is totally dynamic and table view contain sections and cell under it all the things are dynamic. I have a button action outside the table view which is used to add the selected cell data. Now i want to restrict the button that it does not add the data till all the cell under the sections are selected. I want user to first check the cells and than add through add button. My code for the table view is this,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return AddonCategoryModel!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

         return AddonCategoryModel![section].name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 34
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

         return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return AddonCategoryModel![section].addonItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = addonTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addonCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMenuDetailAddonTVC

        cell.addonTitleLbl.text = AddonCategoryModel![indexPath.section].addonItems[indexPath.row].name
        cell.priceLbl.text = String(AddonCategoryModel![indexPath.section].addonItems[indexPath.row].price)


        if selection[indexPath.section].isSelected[indexPath.row] {
             cell.radioBtn.setImage(UIImage (named: "radio"), for: UIControlState.normal)
          addonItemName = cell.addonTitleLbl.text!
          addonItemprice = AddonCategoryModel![indexPath.section].addonItems[indexPath.row].price
          addonItemId = AddonCategoryModel![indexPath.section].addonItems[indexPath.row].addonPKcode
          addonItemNameArray.append(addonItemName)
          addonItemPriceArray.append(addonItemprice)
          addonItemIdArray.append(addonItemId)

          let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(addonItemName, forKey: "addonItemName")
            defaults.set(addonItemprice, forKey: "addonItemPrice")
            defaults.set(addonItemId, forKey: "addonItemId")

            defaults.synchronize()

        }
        else {

            cell.radioBtn.setImage(UIImage (named: "uncheckRadio"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }

        cell.radioBtn.tag = indexPath.row
```

//            cell.radioBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return cell
    }

My screen looks like this,
[image]

Comment: are you done with radio checked and unchecked button images?

Comment: yes its working properly, just i want that the user cannot add any item till it should select all the cell from the table view. @PPL

Comment: ok, please wait giving you answer

Comment: in you didSected make the button highlited or enable,

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to set selected true and false based on user have selected the row or deselected the row, then just check in your data set is anything selected if yes then make the button highlighted/enable else disable/unhighlighted

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selection[indexPath.section].isSelected = true
    tableView.reloadData()
    CheckIfAnyOneIsSelected()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   selection[indexPath.section].isSelected = false
   tableView.reloadData()
   CheckIfAnyOneIsSelected()
}

func CheckIfAnyOneIsSelected() {
    //loop through your array and check if anyone is selected if yes break the loop and set the button to enable
    //else make the button disable

   var anyOneSelecte = false
   for singleModel in AddonCategoryModel {
      for item in addonItems {
        if item.isSelected == true 
        anyOneSelecte = true
        break;
      }
   }

   if anyOneSelecte {
      //enable your button 
   } else {
     //disable your button
   }
}
```

Comment: i have used custom radio buttons, u r saying about default check buttons.  and my add button action is outside of the table view. @Iraniya Naynesh

Comment: that what I'm saying when you click the cell make the  selection[indexPath.section].isSelected = true and reload the table and then CheckIfAnyOneIsSelected if yes make the "my add button enable/disable" , add button is not doing anything to tableview its dosen't matter where it is, you just want to make it disable enable if something is selected/deselected right?

Comment: but this scenario will work if user select any cell under one section. will it check that for all sections cell? @Iraniya Naynesh

Comment: In that case while checking you have to loop though AddonCategoryModel, setting part will work no matter which section you select, and while checking you have to loop through all the sections

Comment: how can i loop through the section and in my function i have to apply loop? @Iraniya Naynesh

Comment: and in " if selection[indexPath.section].isSelected[indexPath.row] {" what is selection you should update that, added how to loop

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo, Let's say you have two Model classes,

```
class AddOnCategoryModel {
    var name: String = ""
    var arrValues = [Category]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Category {
    var name: String = ""
    var price : String = ""
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

and following is the `mainArray`,

```
    for i in 0...2 {
        let model = AddOnCategoryModel(name: "Section \(i)")
        for j in 0...3 {
            let cate = Category()
            cate.name = "Category \(j)"
            model.arrValues.append(cate)
        }
        mainArray.append(model)
    }
```

Now considering you have following `ListTableCell`

[image]

There are two `IBOutlets`

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblTemp: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnRadio: UIButton!
```

FYI. Please set `btnRadio` `default` and `selected` image properly.

Your `UITableViewDataSource` methods,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return mainArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainArray[section].arrValues.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListTableCell") as! ListTableCell
    let category = mainArray[indexPath.section]
    cell.lblTemp.text = category.arrValues[indexPath.row].name
    cell.btnRadio.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tag = indexPath.section
    cell.btnRadio.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnRadioTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return mainArray[section].name
}
```

Please find `btnRadioTapped` method,

```
@objc func btnRadioTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! ListTableCell

    let addOnModel = mainArray[cell.tag]
    let category = addOnModel.arrValues[sender.tag]
    category.isSelected = sender.isSelected
}
```

Not let's check all checkbox's are selected or not in button tap event like this,

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var isCheckedAll = true
    for (_ , item) in mainArray.enumerated() {
        let value = item.arrValues.filter({$0.isSelected==false})
        if value.count > 0 {
            isCheckedAll = false
            break;
        }
    }

    print("Done ", isCheckedAll)
}
```

It will return true if all `radioButtons` are selected, and return false if any one `radioButton` is not selected.

Let me know in case of any queries. This is just demo, you have to do minor changes as per your final requirements.

**UPDATE**

Please find `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method below,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let model = mainArray[indexPath.section]
    let category = model.arrValues[indexPath.row]
    category.isSelected = !category.isSelected

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ListTableCell
    cell.btnRadio.isSelected = category.isSelected
}
```

Comment: bro i have set my own logic on the selection of radio button, because there are some condition on the cell selection under each section. so if it is possible to edit your answer according to my logic. @PPL

Comment: Yes you can set your logic accordingly but this is the perfect answer for your question and it is working, you have to update btnRadioTapped method according to your condition

Comment: my radio button logic is not set in button action it is set in didSelect delegate. button is just to add the selected cell data. @PPL

Comment: @raheem then it will be very nice, let me update my answer, so you don't want to check radioButton on didSelect of UITableView?

Comment: @raheem Please find updated answer and remove btnRadioTapped method

Comment: @raheem are you done with it? if it works for you, please accept and upvote, it will also increase your accept ratio and other user finds it helpful